# The instance member 'myString' can't be accessed in an initializer. TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
String firstName = ''; 

TextEditingController fnameEditController = TextEditingController(text:firstName);
```

I get the error when trying to add a string to TextEditingController(text:firstName)
the error:

```
The instance member 'firstName' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondartimplicit_this_reference_in_initializer
String firstName
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course that can not work..

Try doing it in initState like this

```
String firstName = '';
late TextEditingController _controller;

@override
initState() {
    // this will work
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: firstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't because this 'firstName' is not a constant variable. You can assign it by making constant variable like

```dart
  static const String firstName = '';

  TextEditingController fnameEditController =
      TextEditingController(text: firstName);
```

Also, as @emanuel sanga answered, you can use `initState`

For more

- [dart language guides](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)